# C# application deployment on a network share folder

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, setup-deployment

I have developed a c# application and used sql server 2008 r2 for database. Now I want to do is install this application and SQL Server 2008 in a shared folder in PC1 and access this application from PC2. But use same single database in PC1. (When data inserted to c# application from PC2, data saved in database in PC1.)

This is a Users Information Handling System. Receipt print option also available in this application. 
PC1 and PC2 both are connected through LAN.

can anybody tell me how to do this.
from "creating set up file" up to deploying it on shared folder.
(if its not windows installer strategy)

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to install the application in the shared folder, you need to think about Code Access Security. By default, the .net execute will not run from shared folders. 
Refer the below links.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0(v=vs.90).aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/07/27/443975.aspx

The .NET Framework comes with a utility called CasPol.exe that can be used to tweak trust policies that result in the above-mentioned security exceptions.

The primary command line towards achieving this is -

CasPol.exe -m -ag 1.2 -url file://Network_PC_Name/Share_Name/* FullTrust


First install the application in PC1 as usual, access it from the shared folder from PC2.
You need to use normal / default windows setup to create the deployment option.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/Setup08232007071849AM/Setup.aspx

Please let me know, if you need further information.

Hope this helps you.
```